# $_SESSION in browserless script?

Tags: php, session, command-line

I'm making a script that accesses a framework that handles a rather large system. The scripting is purely command line, to eventually run on automatically.

Some of the classes use $_SESSION variables. To reproduce the content of these classes without, would be rather extensive. Is there any way to set the $_SESSION variables to be able to use these classes without rewriting them?

Comment: Do you want to be able to use `$_SESSION` vars between multiple scripts (or multiple executions of the same script) or simply `$_SESSION` as a standard array?

Comment: $_SESSION doesn't have to go between multiple scripts, but we may encounter multiple executions of the same script that all need their own $_SESSION. The current framework relies too heavily on $_SESSION imo, but I don't have the time to rewrite it all.

Comment: So simply set session path (using [`session_save_path()`](http://php.net/session_save_path)) and you should be fine with `session_start()`. All executions will have different session.

Answer (score 1):

No. If PHP is called in a CLI context then the `$_SESSION` superglobal array is never created, and it is not possible to declare a custom superglobal in PHP.

I would suggest putting the script somewhere web-accessible, even simply a custom vhost running on `127.0.0.1`, and calling the script via wget, cURL, snarf, or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to set whatever you need to before you call those classes:

```
$_SESSION['myvar'] = 'whatever';
```

Comment: Not working. Not saving through the classes. I think Sammitch might be right, but I don't have that option... :(